# Node server: code weight and server performance

Tags: node.js, memory-management

I would like to know how important could be the impact between using a 15.5k library just for doing very simple validations, and, using my own 1k super-simple validation class, in the time when I'll have more than 10k users on my system (Node + Mongo running on a super pentium 8 core 32gb ram). 
Is it worst to care about this 14.5k of code?

I cant find any clue in my so bleak but always wondering mind.

I'll apretiate very much your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice thing about server development is that you usually have significant RAM available and the code is generally loaded just once at the startup of the server so load time is not part of the user experience.

Because of these, you'd be hard pressed to even measure a meaningful impact between a 1k library and a 15k library.  You might care about 15k of memory usage per active user, but you will not care about an extra 15k of code loaded into memory one time and it will not affect your server performance in any way.

So, I'd say you should not worry about skrimping on code size (within reason).  Instead, pick the tool that best solves your problem, makes your development quickest and the most reliable.  And, where possible, use what has been built and tested before rather than build your own from scratch.  That will leave you more development time to spend on the things that really matter to making your website better, different or great.  Or, it will get you to market faster.

For reference, 15k is 0.000045% of your total computer's RAM.

Comment: Hi JFriend, I thank you very much for your reply! So despite it's not meaningful in memory, what about CPU ussage? If I have 10k user interacting with a server-side program that is 15k heavier, does this mean that the server will have to process 15k MORE on each request?

Comment: @EduardoG.R. - code is sitting in memory.  It does not cost anything to sit there.  If you're worried about whether one library is more efficient with the CPU than the other on a given operation than the other, then you can benchmark that, but the code size is irrelevant to the performance.  You'd have to measure performance to know which is better - the larger one is just as likely to perform better as the smaller one.  No - it will not have to process 15k more on each request.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jfriend00. There's almost no impact on memory/performance for the code sizes you describe. You can always benchmark different modules according to your usage profile and choose by yourself. However,  I think you should ask yourself some other (similar) questions -

1. Why the package I use is so 'big'? maybe there's a much 'smaller' one
   that does the same job with the same performance. When I say big or small here I mean in terms of functionality. Most of the times you'd want to go with minimum functionality, even if its size might seem big. If you use a validation module that also validates emails, but you don't need it - doesn't mean that you shouldn't use it, just know the tradeoffs - it might get updated more frequently because bugs in the email validation that might cause other bugs in integer validations that you use, you have more code to read if you want your production code to feel more safe (explained bellow).
2. Does the package function as I expect? (read the tests)
3. Is the package I use "secured"/"OK for production"? Read the code of the packages you use, make sure there isn't something fishy going on - usually node packages are not that big because most are minimal (I never used it, but I know https://requiresafe.com/ exists for these types of questions - you might want to check it out). Note that if they are larger in size that might mean you would have to read more code.
4. Ask these questions (and others of you feel you should) recursively on the package' dependencies.